# Apps Script timezone is off one hour

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having some issues with using the date/ time in Apps Script. Can anyone tell me where the different values are coming from and where I need to change things to get consistency across the script>

If I use the below function it logs the time with an hour offset (-1 hour).

```
function testDate(){
 var date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
  Logger.log(date);
}
```

You can see the logging output in the image below. It displays the log entry being added as 10:09 but the log output value added from the function is 09:09. Where is the 09:09 coming from and how can I change this to get the correct time for London GMT?

I've included the timezone of the project so you can see this. I've also highlighted the last modified time which also seems to be incorrect.

Just to note - this script is not connected to a spreadsheet so there is no timezone info coming from that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now it's BST, which is an hour off UTC/GMT. To get the current time in your locale use toLocaleString().

```
  Logger.log(new Date().toGMTString());
  Logger.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
  Logger.log(new Date().toUTCString());
  Logger.log(new Date().toISOString());
```

gives these results

```
[14-08-22 10:46:03:660 BST] Fri, 22 Aug 2014 09:46:03 GMT
[14-08-22 10:46:03:660 BST] 22 August 2014 10:46:03 BST
[14-08-22 10:46:03:660 BST] Fri, 22 Aug 2014 09:46:03 GMT
[14-08-22 10:46:03:661 BST] 2014-08-22T09:46:03.661Z
```

Comment: I suppose this creates a new question but how would I take the value returned from toLocaleString() and format that in a way that mysql datetime would be happy?

Comment: You can control the date string representation using [Utilities.FormatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Answer (score 0):

When you write `new Date().toISOString()`, the returned value is always in UTC ([see doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)), that's to say  "GMT+00"

But London (as far as I know) uses daylight savings in the summer (British Summer Time -BST in short-, and even if temperature is low in western Europe XD, we are still in summer !) which is GMT+01.

The difference is there.

The last modified field in script Properties is in UTC, as one can see thanks to the `Z` in the time stamp (Z coming from Zulu in military time or Zero if you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

The questioner's comment indicates that he'd also like the output formatted ISO style, so I expanded on Bruce's `new Date().toLocaleString()` approach and came up with the following:

```
var dateTimeArray = new Date().toLocaleString().split(" ");

var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

/*
Return the 2 digit number associated with the "toLocaleString" spelt-out month:
1) Get the index value of the month from the array item
2) Add 1 to it (because it's zero-indexed)
3) Convert it to a string
4) Left pad all month numbers with a zero
5) Get the last 2 digits
*/
var monthNumber = ('0' + (months.indexOf(dateTimeArray[1])+1).toString()).slice(-2);

Logger.log('Before: '+new Date().toLocaleString())
Logger.log('After: '+dateTimeArray[2]+'-'+monthNumber+'-'+dateTimeArray[0]+' '+dateTimeArray[3]);
```

From the Logs window, here is some sample output:

```
[16-07-08 23:57:28:217 BST] Before: 08 July 2016 23:57:28 BST
[16-07-08 23:57:28:218 BST] After: 2016-07-08 23:57:28
```